# How to make user's text input searched for on google

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

Hi, I am trying to make the user's input in the text field get searched on google, here is the code I currently have;

```
-(IBAction)searchInfo: (id)sender {
NSString *query = [textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/%@", query]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];;
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

I have linked  the text field to the (IBAction) button now i am just trying to make whatever the user types into the search field to get searched on Google and appear on my webview.

Answer (score 1):

Your Google query was wrong, and could've been fixed by looking at how Google formats search queries. I wanted to see it for myself so I wrote the code.

```
NSMutableString *searchText = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"https://www.google.com/#q="];
[searchText appendString:[textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"]];

NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:searchText]];

[self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

Will work.

Comment: Thank you very much Peter, much appreciated, but on my one it comes up with an error saying that the property webView is not found, the line of code where the error occurs is; [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];

Comment: I also tried creating the property for webView but when i enter an input in the text field the web view doesn't display the input search on Google not sure why.

Comment: You've got to hookup a web view in a story board or a nib and add it as a property. Same with the textfield.